# How to download global SOC and clay soil datasets?

Tags: data, soilgrids

I just wanted to clarify the best way to access the latest release of SoilGrids (5 Dec 2019). Are the datasets for clay (CLYPPT)at: https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/data/recent/ the same as https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/data/preview/clay/? Or are these the older versions?

Answer (score 2):

No, they are different versions at this stage. In the [`recent`](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/data/recent/) folder is the most recent release, dating back to early 2017. In the [`preview`](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/data/preview/) folder are the grids released in December of 2019.

There are more details in the README files:

- [data/README.md](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/data/README.md) - describes the content of each data folder.
- [recent/README.md](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/data/recent/README.md) - notes for the 2017 release.
- [preview/README.md](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/data/preview/README.md) - notes for the 2019 preview.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Do you have any recommendations on the fastest way to get these layers into GEE (loaded as Geotiffs) or if anyone has already loaded it?